# Why this code of capturing picture from a device don't run properly?

Tags: android, android-image-capture

I was just trying to write a code to capture an image and save that image in default directory with a name test.jpg. My device do capture the image but it runs the else part of the test case and shows error capturing image.In xml file there is only a button and android:onClick is set to process

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private File imagefile;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
public void process(View v)
{
    Toast.makeText(this,"Inside the process",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent  intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    imagefile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"test.jpg");
    Uri temp = Uri.fromFile(imagefile);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,temp);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY,1);
    startActivityForResult(intent,0);


}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode==0)
    {
        switch (resultCode){
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                if(imagefile.exists())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this,"File was saved at "+imagefile.getAbsolutePath(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Error captureing image",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Cast Your Button in onCreate() method

Comment: @Yashajabiya i did , but still the same

Comment: Add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>` and request for camera permission .

Comment: I have taken permission in the manifest file , though it is not needed , still doesn't work @KeLiuyue

Comment: `Android 6.0` need require dynamic permissions .

Comment: Try to log data.getData().

Comment: Ok so tell me what should i do, i have taken permission in manifest @KeLiuyue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.Use checkSelfPermission**

**2.Use requestPermissions**

**3.Use onRequestPermissionsResult**

- If permission is granted , you can do something you want ,else you should do `requestPermissions` in your code .
- If you request permissions,you can deal with result in `onRequestPermissionsResult` method .And if permissions granted , you can do something you want ,else deal with that permission Denied .

Try this .

```
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA = 0;

// process in your code
public void process(View view) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
    } else {
        // permission_granted
        callMethod();
    }
}

/**
 * do something you want
 */
public void callMethod() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Inside the process", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    imagefile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "test.jpg");
    Uri temp = Uri.fromFile(imagefile);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, temp);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}

/**
 * onRequestPermissionsResult
 *
 * @param requestCode
 * @param permissions
 * @param grantResults
 */
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission granted
            callMethod();
        } else {
            // Permission Denied
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return;
    }
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

Comment: Good luck to you.@adnan_aust